# GCloud: Debug "function crashed out of request scope"

Tags: javascript, error-handling, gcloud, serverless-framework

I'm running a **GCloud** **function**, which seems to **crash** **silently**, without any kind of error trace.

Everything works perfectly in the **emulator** but crashes when running on **GCloud**!

The following message shows up in the function's logs:

`Error: function crashed out of request scope Function killed.`

Any idea on how to debug this?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I think this issue has to do with what you are returning, and how you returning it. In the production environment, if you do not properly return a promise your function will be killed since it assumes your work is done. locally, that will probably not happen so the bug is invisible. Look here, for an example: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/78