# Error: function crashed out of request scope Function invocation was interrupted

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a Cloud Function that reads several lines from a .csv file and sends one HTTP request for each line, but I'm getting the error above.

This error has been asked before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583806/error-function-crashed-out-of-request-scope-function-killed), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773905/vue-and-firebase-issue-error-function-crashed-out-of-request-scope-function-in) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44899374/gcloud-debug-function-crashed-out-of-request-scope) to list a few), but in all of these cases, the issue was that the function didn't return a promise that would resolve only after every asynchronous operation.

From my understanding of how `async` works, my code doesn't seem to have this issue. Here's the gist of it, removing some specific details:

```js
const request = require('request-promise-native');
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

exports.sendData = async (data, context) => {
    const [file] = await storage.bucket(data.bucket).file(data.name).download();
    const [header, ...table] = file.toString('utf8').split('\n').map(row => row.split(','));
    const rows = table.map(
        row => header.reduce((obj, col, i) => {
            obj[col] = row[i];
            return obj;
        }, {})
    );

    const paramList = rows.map(({ csv_field1, csv_field2 }) => ({
        req_field1: csv_field1,
        req_field2: csv_field2,
        // etc.
    }));

    let errors = 0;
    console.log(`Sending ${paramList.length} rows...`);
    await Promise.all(paramList.map(async (param, i) => {
        try {
            await request.get({ url: "", qs: param }); // Endpoint removed
            if ((i + 1) % 10000 == 0) {
                console.log(`${i + 1} rows ${paramList.length} sent.`);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Request failed for row ${i + 1} .\n\n${e}`);
            errors++;
        }
    }));
    console.log(`Done.`);
    if (errors > 0) {
        console.log(`Total errors: ${errors}`);
    }
};
```

The above code works just fine for a couple of lines (10), but the error begins showing up when trying with bigger numbers (1000). The "Done." message also didn't appear in the logs, so it doesn't seem that the function is reaching the end.

Any clues?

Comment: Rewrote the code to use promises and tried the Node.js 6 runtime and it worked. Not sure if there was anything wrong with the code or if it was an issue with the Node.js 8 runtime.

Comment: I've got exactly the same symptoms, but in quite a big project that I really didn't want to rewrite for Node 6... It works fine until the number of outgoing http requests reaches a few hundred, and then starts crashing with that helpful error.

Comment: sounds like the same problem I have...  any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on my project.
I resolved it by downgrading runtime from node8 to node6